# Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, rakefile

On Rails 6 (6.1.4.1) we had a RakeFile that would run a subset of tests. For example:

```
# lib/tasks/carrier.rake
namespace :test do
  task carriers: "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files =  FileList["test/models/carrier_test.rb",
                           "test/controllers/admin/carriers/**/*_test.rb",
                           "test/system/admin/carriers/**/*_test.rb"]
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end
end
```

This would execute just fine when called:

```
rails test:carriers
```

However, somewhere along the way, something changed and we began seeing errors when trying to run our RakeFile test tasks. (I haven't tracked down exactly what changed and when it changed -- perhaps it was part of the Rails 7 release.) Here's the error we began seeing:

```
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Shoulda

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
^^^^^^^
/path/test/test_helper.rb:15:in `<main>'
/path/test/models/carrier_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
/path/lib/tasks/carriers.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:carriers
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The error appeared with no changes to our tests or environment configuration. (Running a full `rake` worked just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

When reviewing the source code for [Rails::TestUnit::Runner](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb), I came across `rake_run`. Simply replacing `Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run` with `Rails::TestUnit::Runner.rake_run` addressed the issue (no other changes required):

```
# lib/tasks/carrier.rake
namespace :test do
  task carriers: "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files =  FileList["test/models/carrier_test.rb",
                           "test/controllers/admin/carriers/**/*_test.rb",
                           "test/system/admin/carriers/**/*_test.rb"]
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.rake_run(test_files)
  end
end
```